# How to create a roller like animation? Similar to slot machine

Tags: flutter

I want to create a custom animation, basically something like a slot machine, but I want the user to be able to move up/down each block with letters by his finger, not spin automatically.
I tried looking into this library: https://pub.dev/packages/roll_slot_machine/example but doesn't seem to fit my needs. Can I get any hints how to approach this?

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`CupertinoPicker`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html) can archive similar like this. You can use `Stack` for background selection, `Container`'s decoration to improve view.

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=87bd7b97485e9233a2912ed4fc35c06e)

[image]

```dart
class CustomRollStateMachine extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomRollStateMachine({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomRollStateMachineState createState() => _CustomRollStateMachineState();
}

class _CustomRollStateMachineState extends State<CustomRollStateMachine> {
  int aCode = 'A'.codeUnitAt(0);
  int zCode = 'Z'.codeUnitAt(0);

  late List<String> alphabets = List<String>.generate(
    zCode - aCode + 1,
    (index) => String.fromCharCode(aCode + index),
  );

  List<String?> result = List.filled(4, null);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 124,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: RollerSlot(
                  callback: (p0) {
                    setState(() {
                      result[0] = p0;
                    });
                  },
                  data: alphabets,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: RollerSlot(
                  callback: (p0) {
                    setState(() {
                      result[1] = p0;
                    });
                  },
                  data: alphabets,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: RollerSlot(
                  callback: (p0) {
                    setState(() {
                      result[2] = p0;
                    });
                  },
                  data: alphabets,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: RollerSlot(
                  callback: (p0) {
                    setState(() {
                      result[3] = p0;
                    });
                  },
                  data: alphabets,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Text("Result: ${result.join()}")
      ],
    );
  }
}


class RollerSlot extends StatelessWidget {
  const RollerSlot({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
    required this.callback,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> data;
  final Function(String) callback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      child: CupertinoPicker(
          itemExtent: 24.0,
          onSelectedItemChanged: (value) => callback(data[value]),
          children: data
              .map(
                (e) => Text(e),
              )
              .toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is amazing, thanks. Do you know by any chance if the selected class can be styled? Talking about the grey background on the letter

Comment: a trick can be done using `selectionOverlay` on `CupertinoPicker`.  like  `selectionOverlay: Container(color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(.5)),`